# using md-grid on material-design

Tags: grid, angular-material

i am very new to angular material, i want to implement grid system in my design, what i want in my design is i want certain div to be displayed on right button of the page which will shrink to bottom as page is scrolled down. i have tried using md-cards and md-grid from angular-material demos, but i cannot get output as i expected can any one help me on this?
[image: i want chat box to be fixed on the right bottom of the page.]